# Image defined in "Content:" should be centered relative to its parent

Tags: css, styles

I have community (salesforce) page, in which, I dont have access to the DOM. I can only play with CSS to edit styling to brand it as per the requirements.

Consider the below scenario:

```css
.selfServiceArticleLayout .warning, .warningDiv {
    border: 2px solid #DE3737;
    margin-bottom: 22px;
}

.note:before, .warning:before, .important:before, .tip:before {
    content: url(https://xxx/some_icon);
    width: 29px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 15px;
    top: unset;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<p class="warning" data-aura-rendered-by="12:173;a"><span class="autonumber"><span><b>Note: </b></span></span> You must have at least one request type selected. You can select multiple request types. A quick brown fox, jumed over the lazy dogYou can select multiple request types. A quick brown fox, jumed over the lazy dogYou can select multiple request types. A quick brown fox, jumed over the lazy dogYou can select multiple request types. A quick brown fox, jumed over the lazy dog. </p>
```

## Result

[image]

**[Check on Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8qexp03k/)**

Comment: Can you please include more HTML source to test a most accurate scenario? warningDiv is missing

Comment: As Zhephard said, your code doesn't contain the element you are actually asking the question about. Please make sure that the code you supply reproduces the issue you are having or it is useless.

Comment: "warningDiv" has nothing to do with the question. It is the "warning" , inside which , I have icon/image that needs to be vertically centered. I can't paste entire HTML, as it can't be edited anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```css
.wrapper {
  display: table;
}

.content {
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  display: table-cell; //this is important so it follows the rule below
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

And this could be the HTML (i added a lorem ipsum so the container grows in height and you can check how the first content stays vertically aligned to middle)

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">X</div>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

Are you able to update the icon rendering prop like this?

```css
.note:before,
.warning:before,
.important:before,
.tip:before {
  //content: url(https://xxx/some_icon);
  width: 29px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: unset;
  margin-top: 5px;
  background-image: url(https://xxx/some_icon); //use the icon as a background image
  background-position: center left; //then position it
}
```

**UPDATE**
Try this:

```css
.warning {
    border: 2px solid #DE3737;
    position: relative;
}

.warning:before {
    /*content: url(https://aer.eu/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/twitter-logo-4.png);*/
    content: ' ';
    background-image: url("https://aer.eu/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/twitter-logo-4.png");
    background-position: left;
    width: 29px;height:29px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 35px;  
    top: 40%;
}
```

This may be a possibility considering you may never know the exact div height, you can use a top positioning between 40% or 45%

Comment: I can't have extra class, I can't change the HTML, already present in the question, cant use JS either. As I mentioned, DOM is not in my control.

Comment: Are you able to change the icon from content to background image?

Comment: please check my jsfiddle example. using image in either content or background-image doesnt work. It puts the image at the top left. If I apply top-margin, then the image would not be centered if the text grows/shrinks.

Comment: Applied your CSS, but the image is still appearing at the top-left, instead of left center. P.S. I have also tried `background-position: left center`.

Comment: Just added an alternative using your fiddle

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work either. Can't we know the height of container? so we can set `margin-top:(heightOf_container - heightof_container-heightof_image)` something like that?

Comment: I'm afraid with only css you can't achieve that, you would need to use JavaScript for that